# Selected among, out of, from, or from between?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I want to say that my paper was selected from a bunch of others, to emphasize that my paper was impressive. How do I say that in a correct way and without using too many words?

What I have so far:

> I was interviewed to discuss the findings of my paper, which was selected out of all/among/from all the other reports...

Comment: Btw, *among* also requires *from*: "from among". Do not use "other". "which was selected  from among all the reports... " HTH.

Comment: "I want to say that my paper was selected from a bunch of others". Dude. Dude. **You just did.** And you didn't even notice. You answered your question before even asking it.

Comment: What you should really be concerned about is not the *from* but the *other*. How can you select *your* paper from *other* papers? That is just not humanly possible. You can select your paper from all papers, but not from papers that are expressly not yours.

Answer (score 1):

**choose among**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/choose+among) an idiom

choose among (people or things)

> to select from a group of options.

As in:

> I was interviewed to discuss the findings of my paper, which was
>   chosen among all the submissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to boast that your paper was unique you could use the expression **singled out** as in :

"I was interviewed to discuss the findings of my paper, which was singled out from all the other reports..."

Definition of single out in Merriam_Webster online:

"to treat or to speak about (someone or something in a group) in a way that is different from the way one treats or speaks about others The coach singled out the players who played poorly. The reviewer singled her performance out for praise/criticism. —often used as (be) singled out She was singled out for special treatment."